# How can I check presence of flag at compile time?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am using the `-LITTLE`  flag for choosing **little endian** calculation and
`-BIG` for **big endian** calculation in my project while compiling.

```
#ifdef LITTLE   
   {    
    // i'm using i for operating one loop 
   }
   #endif

 /* If the system is big-endian, store bytes in array as forward order */
#ifdef  BIG 
   {
   // using i for loop
   }
   #endif
```

like

```
gcc -LITTLE my_c_file.c
```

I want to check if user hasn't given any of flag at compile time then compilation does not takes place and give an error.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you mean `gcc -DLITTLE`.

You can use something like:

```
#if !defined(LITTLE) && !defined(BIG)
#error either LITTLE or BIG must be defined
#endif
```

At a guess, you might also want:

```
#if defined(LITTLE) && defined(BIG)
#error only one of LITTLE or BIG must be defined
#endif
```

Of course, it's better if you can write code that doesn't care about the endianness of the maching that you are running on and avoid the whole mess.

Comment: but where should i put this .??

Comment: @Mr.32: Personally, I'd put it in a common header file and `#include` it before any bit of code that relies on one of `LITTLE` or `BIG` being defined.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
#if !defined(LITTLE) && !defined(BIG)
#error "Either LITTLE or BIG has to be defined"
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You can detect the byte sex of the platform automatically. See [boost/detail/endian.hpp](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/boost/detail/endian.hpp).